# How to change admin url in local server in Integrate WordPress into Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

i have setup e local mageto1 site from live which have magento WordPress integrate.So whenever i try to open local server admin of WordPress it automatically goes to live site how change setup that url for local site Thank you.

Comment: search in database there will be stored live url so find and replace from phpmyadmin .

Comment: i have seared in phpadmin but did't find any thing there was only a serialized value with a <a> tag i have changed it but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the URLs in the database, and the tables are slightly different than typical WP table names.

Try these                                 :

```
UPDATE wp_blog_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl.com', 'http://www.newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_blog_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl.com','http://www.newurl.com');
UPDATE wp_blog_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl.com', 'http://www.newurl.com');
UPDATE wp_blog_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl.com','http://www.newurl.com');
```

Once complete, navigate to http://www.newurl.com/[PATH_SET_IN_FISHPIG_CONFIG]/wp-login.php in a browser, and configure the new database details to generate your wp-config.php file. We configure the PATH to `blog`.

[image]